# Shouldn't This JavaScript Code Not Work?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

So, I have this bit of JS code for a canvas animation:

```
function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height;
}
```

Since the requestAnimationFrame bit comes before the rest of the code, shouldn't this just be an infinite empty loop that doesn't run any code inside the function? It obviously isn't, as the rest of the code works, but my question is why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame` (rAF) doesn't call your function immediately. It schedules it to be called just before the browser paints the next frame (sort of like like `setTimeout` schedules a function to be called after [roughly] a given number of milliseconds). So what this code is doing is setting up a handler that will get called for each frame.

So assuming something calls `animate` at some point to start the process, it goes like this:

1. `animate` is called

   - It calls rAF to schedule a call before the next frame
   - It clears the rectangle
2. Browser reaches the point it's about to render a frame

   - Browser calls `animate`

     - See #1